# Retrieve template parameters from CXXConstructExpr in Clang AST

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

Say I have a variable declaration like this:

```
std::vector<MyType> myVector(1);
```

This is represented as a `CXXConstructExpr` in the Clang AST. I have a matcher that finds this `CXXConstructExpr`, but I'd like to extract the decl for `MyType` from it.

I've tried all sorts of things, but nothing seems to work:

```
const CXXConstructExpr* construct = Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<CXXConstructExpr>("expr");
construct->getConstructor()->getTemplateSpecializationArgs()  // Always nullptr
construct->getConstructor()->getParent()  // Seems to lose the template parameters
construct->getConstructor()->getDescribedTemplate()  // Always nullptr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a matcher:

```
varDecl(
  has(
    cxxConstructExpr()
  )
 ,hasType(
    classTemplateSpecializationDecl().bind(sp_dcl_bd_name_)
  )
).bind(var_bd_name_);
```

It starts with the VarDecl and traverses to the type, which is a `ClassTemplateSpecializationDecl` buried in vector's `ClassTemplateDecl`. In the callback, one can work from the `ClassTemplateSpecializationDecl` to the template argument list, and operate on the individual template arguments:

```
using CTSD = ClassTemplateSpecializationDecl;
CTSD * spec_decl =
    const_cast<CTSD *>(result.Nodes.getNodeAs<CTSD>(sp_dcl_bd_name_));
VarDecl * var_decl =
    const_cast<VarDecl *>(result.Nodes.getNodeAs<VarDecl>(var_bd_name_));
if(spec_decl && var_decl) {
  // get the template args
  TemplateArgumentList const &tal(spec_decl->getTemplateArgs());
  for(unsigned i = 0; i < tal.size(); ++i){
    TemplateArgument const &ta(tal[i]);
    // is this arg a type arg? If so, get that type
    TemplateArgument::ArgKind k(ta.getKind());
    std::string argName = "";
    if(k==TemplateArgument::ArgKind::Type){
      QualType t = ta.getAsType();
      argName = t.getAsString();
    }
    // Could do similar actions for integral args, etc...
    std::cout << "For variable declared at "
      << corct::sourceRangeAsString(var_decl->getSourceRange(),&sm) << ":"
      << spec_decl->getNameAsString()
      << ": template arg " << (i+1) << ": " << argName << std::endl;
  } // for template args
} // if
```

For this code:

```
struct B{int b_;};
std::vector<B> vb(1);
```

this produces:

```
For variable declared at <line:14:1, col:20>:vector: template arg 1: struct B
For variable declared at <col:1, col:20>:vector: template arg 2: class std::__1::allocator<struct B>
```

The full example is in the Code Analysis and Refactoring with Clang Tools examples repo at github: https://github.com/lanl/CoARCT (see apps/TemplateType.cc)

Comment: I had to use hasDescendant() instead of has() because the CXXConstructExpr isn't always a direct child of the VarDecl, but this otherwise worked.